# BIRT Designer: Determining Percentage of Total for Values in a Column

Tags: graph, scripting, birt

I have a data set in BIRT Designer with two columns, one with day of week abbreviation names (Su, M, Tu, etc.) and the other with numerical representations of those days of the week starting at 0 and going to 6 (0, 1, 2, etc.). I want to determine what percentage of the total number of rows that each day of week represents. For example, if I have 100 total rows and 12 of those rows correspond to Su/0, 12% of the total rows are made up of Su.

I would like to perform this same calculation within BIRT and graph (bar graph) those percentages that each day consists of out of the total. I'm just learning how to use BIRT and assume that I need to do some scripting either when making my data set or when specifying the rows when making the chart. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some inspiration from James Jenkins I think I found my answer. It was pretty simple in the end, but all I needed to do was make a new computed column and instead of adding an expression, I simply set the Aggregation to "COUNT". That counts all of the rows in your table and puts that total on each row. That way you can use that total in any calculations that you may need to do. I have added a screenshot for clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use computed columns.

Edit Data set > Computed Columns

The simplest way is to put one column that counts every row, for each day of the week.  You can have a separate column that adds a count if the day of the week is a specific values

```
if (row["Day"] == "Su"){
1
}
```

I should add: that you can use a 'data' element in your table to compute the percentage.  A 'Dynamic Text' item could also be used, but the data item gives you a binded value that you can make better use of later if needed.

**Edit**
To get a total row count, us a computed column I name mine 'All'

For the Expression use the value "1"

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I think I might have come up with a very simple way to do what I want to do, I just need a little more information. What I have done is count the rows for each day and divided them by the total number of rows to get the percentage. This works for now but is not scalable.

Would you happen to know how to pull this total number of rows out and use it in an expression within BIRT Designer?

Comment: How are you counting the rows now?

Comment: I am not aware of anyway to get rows without using code to count them.

Comment: Do you know what code I could use and where I would put it (computed column or script when defining data)? I have scoured the internet and their documentation but I can't seem to find how to get the total row count.